# How to stop playing sounds on button click to start another sound file?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have two buttons and two songs. If I click the first button, the first sound plays. But if I click the second button while the first sound is playing the second sound starts playing too.
How can I stop other sounds?

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer johnCenaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.john_cena);
    Button johnCenaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.john_cena_button);
    johnCenaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            johnCenaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer haGayPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.id.ha_gay_button);
    Button haGayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ha_gay_button);
    haGayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            haGayPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the other MediaPlayer in clickListener using stop() method.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ha_gay.stop()
    john_cena.start();
}
```

---

If you have many audio files use a single MediaPlayer and change the sources dynamically.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    Button john_cena_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.john_cena_button);
    john_cena_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stopAndPlay(R.raw.john_cena, mediaPlayer);
        }
    });

    Button ha_gay_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ha_gay_button);
    ha_gay_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stopAndPlay(R.raw.ha_gay, mediaPlayer);
        }
    });
}

// This resets the mediaPlayer and starts the given audio
private void stopAndPlay(int rawId, MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawId);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

}
```

Comment: 1. It doesn´t work because if I start the App on my mobile phone it crashes instantly. 2. And what should I do if I have as an example 10 buttons?

Comment: 1. This can't be responsible for the instant crash (Because above code only run when you click the button). 2. You can use a single MediaPlayer(I'll edit the answer with an example).

Comment: Thank youuuu, it finally works. I was looking for this for 1 month.

Comment: Hi, how can I stop the Mediaplayer with a fab?

Comment: @Niggo same as the button

Comment: But I don´t want to stop and start the MediaPlayer again, I just want to stop the mediaplayer. How can I do this?

Comment: Call mediaPlayer.stop()

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Do it same for the other.

```
final MediaPlayer john_cena = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.john_cena);
Button john_cena_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.john_cena_button);
john_cena_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (he_gay.isPlaying()){
             he_gay.stop();
    }
        else if (john_cena.isPlaying()){
            john_cena.seekTo(0);
    }  else{
       john_cena.start();
    }
}
});
```